# Long delays and messed up AJAX responses when running Pylons app via Apache

Tags: apache, http, pylons, fastcgi

I have a Pylons app that I'm trying to set up using Apache and FCGI. The Pylons INI file has this in it:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:Flup#fcgi_thread
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 40100
```

This used to work on an old CentOS server with Pylons 0.9.7, but now I'm trying to set it up on a new one, running Ubuntu 10.04 and Pylons 1.0. I can connect to the app and load main page, but it's very slow. It then makes AJAX requests and the HTTP responses to those are all messed up: sometimes I'll get half of the response text (eg. half a GUID that the server sent), other times there will be HTTP headers and binary junk in the body of the response. Each response is also delayed by about 15 seconds. The app works fine on the same server when using Paster directly.

I've never seen anything like this before. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, turning off the **gzip** module in Apache fixed the problem. I still don't know why it happened.